# How to determine author, creation date, etc. of SSRS report within Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

After a report has been deployed we are able to easily see the author, creation date, modified by and modified date.

That information is tied to the report created in Visual Studio?

I've tried searching the code of the report and I don't see the information needed. How can we see the information prior to the report being deployed?

Comment: What version of VS? In 2005 there is an Author field available in the development environment Report properties. However, this requires manual entry. The deployed reports will have "Modified"/"Created by" authors set up by the deployment process

Comment: 2012. And I'm looking at reports that are within a project but not deployed. They may need to be clean-out. But I'd like more info before acting.